# How to install pip with a specific python version

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I want to install pip for python 2.7, but I am also having python 3.x but both locations are different. when ever I install or update the pip It is installing in the python 3.x location.

How to install pip for python 2.7?

Comment: Really depends on your system, but you need different pip for python 2. On arch, I have `pip3` and `pip2`.

Comment: Download pip from here for Python 2.7, https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip/1.4.1; uninstall it under your Python 2.7 folder, invoke a command console window, go to the directory where pip was unzipped, you need to run a command similar to "python install.py" then pip would be installed in the same folder.

Comment: what happens if you [install the latest Python 2.7 version (`2.7.9`)](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-279/)? It should have `pip` included: [PEP 477 - Backport ensurepip (PEP 453) to Python 2.7](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0477/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently found the following solution, when you are maintaining python2.x and python 3.x in host system. You can find the pip under Scripts folder.

Try `pip --version` it gives pip version and python version as well

If you want to install package using pip use the following commands.

```
python -m pip install package_name
python2.x -m pip install package_name
```

Which reads the specified python pip module to install the package